# For loops in r to create subsets

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create a subset from an existing data frame where the variable     "Readings" displays values which are greater than the previous reading, as well as the corresponding row entry for the "Time" variable.
The code I have written below only produces "NA" entries.

```
Data$Readings<-0
for (i in 1:nrow(Data)){
Pos.Readings<-Data[Data$Readings[i+1]>Data$Readings[i],]
}
Pos.Readings
```

I would like the new data frame to display the row entries for i and i+1 if i+1>i in the Readings variable.

Here is an example of the data

```
Time      Readings
12:00:00  0.1
12:00:01  0.3
12:00:02  0.45
12:00:03  0.2
12:00:04  0.02
12:00:05  -0.7
12:00:06  -0.25
12:00:07  0.27
```

So, what I am aiming for should look like:

```
Time      Readings
12:00:00  0.1
12:00:01  0.3
12:00:02  0.45
12:00:05  -0.7
12:00:06  -0.25
12:00:07  0.27
```

I have probably gone about writing the for loop incorrectly, but I hope my intentions are clear to all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you care about the absolute value of readings being greater than the previous. If that is the case, try this:

```
comparisons <- Data$Readings[-nrow(Data)]
Data$prevReading <- 0 #or just a really small number that automatically keeps row 1
Data$prevReading[-1] <- comparisons

subsetData <- subset(Data, abs(prevReading) < abs(Readings))
subsetData <- subsetData[c("Time", "Readings")]
```

If you wanted the actual readings being compared and not the absolute values, just get rid of the two `abs()` commands when you subset.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried this solution and it produces the first row only. I can't seem to get it to loop through each row.

Comment: when I used the data you posted, it returned all of the subset that it is supposed to, not just the first row. You don't need to use a loop here though, if these data are ordered chronologically.

Comment: I had gaps in my original data frame, which I have removed, and it now works perfectly. Thank you very much.